# Can I send gzip compressed data through tornado websocket in Python?

Tags: javascript, python, websocket, tornado

I would like to send gzip compressed data from tornado server to javascript client. Here is my code.

```
buf = StringIO()
gfile = gzip.GzipFile(mode='wb', fileobj=buf)
try:
    gfile.write( "hello world" )
finally:
    gfile.close()

compressed_data = buf.getvalue()    
self.write_message( compressed_data )
```

Server side doesn't provide error. But chrome produces an error "Could not decode a text frame as UTF8".

Is there any workaround here?

Comment: Which headers did you set?

Comment: I also tried to set headers but does Websockets require headers? 

Here is a link i found while searching.

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082166/how-to-send-json-header-via-python-tornado-in-a-websocket)

Comment: I guess your client expects a subprotocol that uses utf-8.

Comment: The client interprets the data as utf-8 encoded text and thus fails to decode it. You need to specify the appropriate MIME type: [`application/gzip`](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6713).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `self.write_message(compressed_data, binary=True)` to send a binary message. You'll also need to change the client side of the application to decompress it.

Note that binary data can be difficult to work with in javascript, so you may want to use the websocket compression extension instead of compressing the data yourself (this will make Tornado compress the data automatically, and the browser will decompress it).

To enable this, override [`get_compression_options()`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/websocket.html#tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler.get_compression_options) in your `WebSocketHandler` subclass:

```
def get_compression_options(self):
    return {}
```

An empty dict uses the defaults, or you can return parameters like `{'compression_level': 9}`. When using this mode you'd just write your message as usual instead of compressing it.

Comment: Thanks. I tried doing what you instructed there.

 `def get_compression_options(self):
        return {'compression_level': 9}`

But unfortunately the data is not being compressed. I sent the data normally like this

`msg="hello world"
 self.write_message( msg )`

Comment: How did you determine that the data is not being compressed? The browser will automatically decompress it on the other side. You need to look at the raw network traffic to see whether compression is occurring. That raw network traffic can also be examined with a tool like wireshark to see whether the compression extension is being negotiated by both sides.